# Unique Identification for amazon Echo devices during Skill Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an application using 500 Amazon echo devices and I need a way to uniquely identify from which device the request came from. Is there a way to get a unique identifier of a device during the execution of the Java lambda function for my perticular skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Go to the Alexa Console -> Create/Edit Skill -> Permissions ->
   Enable necessary fields, preferably email in your case
2. Get the requester email during request in fulfilment. Sample code below

*Sample Python code*

```
def get_user_info(access_token):
amazonProfileURL = 'https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token='
r = requests.get(url=amazonProfileURL+access_token)
if r.status_code == 200:
    return r.json()
else:
    return False
```

Comment: can you provide me a java code? that will be helpful.

Comment: For Java code refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512120/how-to-get-amazon-user-email-with-java-in-alexa-skill