# getAccessToken() returns null

Tags: java, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I want to read the customer email to send info, but the AccessToken is always null.

How can I solve it?

```
String accessToken = requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getAccessToken();
                
if(null != accessToken) {
    String url = "https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=" + accessToken;
    JSONObject json = Functions.readJsonFromUrl(url);
    String email = json.getString("email");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Priyam Gupta said, this is solved with api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token= And the code I used to solve it is:

```
String accessToken = requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getAccessToken();
String url = "https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=" + accessToken;
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(url);
String email = json.getString("email");
String name = json.getString("name");
```

Comment: You could have just linked the post you copied the answer from. Original is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512120/how-to-get-amazon-user-email-with-java-in-alexa-skill

Comment: Do you see something different at two pieces of code?
That sentence returns null requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getAccessToken();